# Can I substitute の中で with only で?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Do these pairs of sentences mean the same?

> あの男の人の中で誰が一番かっこいいですか。
> あの男の人で誰が一番かっこいいですか。

> 日本の中で札幌が一番好きな町です。
> 日本で札幌が一番好きな町です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentences of the second pair mean the same.

As for the first pair,

> あの男の人で誰が一番かっこいいですか。

sounds a bit odd because without の中 it looks like a singular *that man*.

> あそこの男の人で誰が一番かっこいいですか。

will be fine.

---

Some other examples (with or without の中で is fine)

- ヨーロッパの国(の中)でどこか一番過ごしやすいですか? Which country is the easiest to live in Europe?
- このクラス(の中)で誰が一番背が高いですか? Who is the tallest in this class?

Here 国 or クラス is naturally understood as a realm that comparison is made.

I guess your confusing has something to do with the fact that この/あの etc + singular noun can be understood as the realm, but without の中, it becomes less obvious. In other words, の中で makes the preceding phrase a realm by meaning *among*, but simply using で means *at/in* and sounds odd.

あの男の人たちの中で makes the "guys over there" a category, but あの男の人で doesn't. あの男の人**たち**で is less odd, but not completely natural. On the other hand あの映画スターで is more acceptable probably because 映画スター is understood as a category more easily.

Comment: Can you add to your answer the difference between で and の中で in this kind of sentence? With your own pairs of examples. I'm still not sure when they are interchangeable.

Comment: @Haragurodanshi Added.